# How to add a game object to another scene at a specific position?

Tags: python, game-engine, objects, scene

Here is some code for getting a object and adding it to another scene:

```
import bge
# to load the scene
bge.logic.addScene('Scene.001')

#find the scene and object

scenes = bge.logic.getSceneList()
for scene in scenes :
    if scene.name == 'Scene.001':
        player= scene.objects['player']

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
ob =bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
ob1=scene.addObject("player",ob)
```

When I play it seem that the "player" from the other scene is added in the camera's position of the current scene.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've edited your question assuming that you want to add the player at a specific position. If this is incorrect or you disagree with my edits, feel free to [edit] it again or roll back my changes.

Comment: If you add more detail on how you add your second scene to your game, I might be able to give you a better way to access that scene. Instead of looping through the scene list every time.

Answer (score 1):

The [add object](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bge.types.KX_Scene.html#bge.types.KX_Scene.addObject) function works by adding the new object (the first parameter) at the location of another game object (the second parameter).

With these two lines you are specifying that it adds the player the at location of the object your script is on (probably your camera).

```
ob =bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
ob1=scene.addObject("player",ob)
```

---

Here is how to fix it.

Add a new empty, parent it to your camera if you need the player always spawning relative to the camera. If you want the player to always spawn in one spot, then do not parent the empty.

Now use the new empty as the location for where you add the player.

```
empty = scene.objects['Empty']
ob1 = scene.addObject(player, empty)
```